# matplotlib - to show dates instead of ordinal number in the x-axis in my plot (stock price vs dates). I am using "toordina()l" to plot the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stock, ordinal

My plot shows on the x-axis the ordinal numbers (from dates) used a good fitting plot. But I want the axis to show dates in the normal format (dd--mm--yyyy) without changing the plot in any way.

Also,

```
ordinalDates = []

for the whole stock cvs:

          dateToNumber = datetime.datetime.toordinal(datetime.date())  
          ordinalDates.append(dateToNumber)
```

I have a list having all the converted dates (in ordinal number). and this list is the one I use to fit the linear regression curve as well as plot it.

[image: Check Image]

Comment: maybe try to cast them to str?

Comment: If you want the dates why do you use numbers?

Comment: @Goyo All the programs (even stock programs like Excel) use number converted to dates (from 1 jan, 1990) to make the time(date) axis evenly separated and spaced. So, I gave matplot ordinal numbers instead of dates.

Also, I didn't know if I could plot a curve with raw dates (mm-dd-yyyy) on one of the axes.

Comment: @a'man Actually you can, look at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert them to a string in a second list:

```
dateToNumber = datetime.datetime.toordinal(datetime.date())  
ordinalDates.append(dateToNumber)
strDates.append(str(datetime.date()))
```

And then update the `xticklabels`:

```
plt.set_xticklabels(strDates)
```

Comment: Works like a knife on butter. Thank you!